# Snapshot returns multiple values

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to go to a second activity and also get some values from firebase.
But, when I print it, it always returns multiple values and only one is the correct value and the others are just null.

For example this is what it prints:

```
null
correct
null
null
null
```

Code:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("StoresData");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (final DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
            TextView storenamego = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.storenamego);
            //The next line returns multiple values containing null
            System.out.println("pleasesee" + snapshot1.child(parkingList.get(position).getStoreid()).child("arname").getValue(String.class));
            storenamego.setText(snapshot1.child(parkingList.get(position).getStoreid()).child("arname").getValue(String.class));
            storenamego.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SpecialityListActivityAr.this, LoggedInAr.class);
                    intent.putExtra("pharmacy_name",snapshot1.child(parkingList.get(position).getStoreid()).child("arname").getValue(String.class));
                    String nameid = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameid");
                    String specialityid = getIntent().getStringExtra("specialtyid");
                    intent.putExtra("username", snapshot1.child(parkingList.get(position).getStoreid()).child("username").getValue(String.class));
                    intent.putExtra("nameid", nameid);
                    System.out.println("NameID:" + nameid);
                    intent.putExtra("supervisor",snapshot1.getKey());
                    String getname = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameofcus");
                    intent.putExtra("nameofcus", getname);
                    String special = getIntent().getStringExtra("speciality");
                    intent.putExtra("asda", special);
                    intent.putExtra("specialtyid", specialityid);
                    String getmob = getIntent().getStringExtra("mob");
                    intent.putExtra("mob", getmob);
                    intent.putExtra("storephone",snapshot1.child(parkingList.get(position).getStoreid()).child("phone").getValue(String.class));
                    intent.putExtra("lng", getIntent().getStringExtra("lng"));
                    intent.putExtra("lat", getIntent().getStringExtra("lat"));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

I think it might be because I have put my `ValueEventListener` in my adapter. If so, can anyone guide me on where I can change its place?

Firebase database structure:

[image: Database structure]

Comment: Can you please post your firebase database structure so that we can understand better? Thank you!

Comment: @ReazMurshed Here you go just added it!!